# Traversing Africa: A Cryptic Journey

Tags: knowledge, geography, cryptic-clues

Each answer is a **place**, **landmark** or **attraction** in Africa, one per country. The answers first traverse all countries on the mainland by crossing land borders, and then the remaining ones go around the continent by sea. Each clue is missing a **country name** from another clue (not the *answer* to that clue, just the name of the country).

Notes:

- By request of the Sanity Preservation Institute, some long names have been shortened. For example, if the full place name is "Xyz Royal National Park", the answer will be just "Xyz" (often with "royal national park" or similar as the definition).
- While many of the answers are pretty obscure, all of them are notable enough to have a separate article on the English Wikipedia.
- I have used the same country names here as Wikipedia uses in its article titles. So Eswatini instead of Swaziland, Ivory Coast instead of Côte d'Ivoire etc.

> 1. Masculine half TV star by wild and unopened [16] waterfall (12)
>   2. [25]'s leader capable before peak mesa (5 8)
>   3. Mountain is returning by [43] with no rail signs, twice (6)
>   4. [50]'s honorific next to violently beat oasis fort (3 9)
>   5. [49]'s first Shakespeare king leads Shakespeare king's lake resort (4 7)
>   6. Non-deceased [12] town without town is former capital (11)
>   7. Grand [4]'s neighbour is ruined city (5 8)
>   8. Agreed, audiovisual [10] with murderous Bundy's parts forms river mouth (8 5)
>   9. Dry lake's unconventional US olives draw in [46] couple (10)
>   10. Chaotic [6] gets a large turn for medium beach (4 4)
>   11. Ape follows girl alongside [42] capital's leaders to sanctuary (4 2 6)
>   12. Aged user interface about the case of [54]' capital gorge (7)
>   13. Get one back inside [45]'s borders leads to capital (6)
>   14. Forest capital of Neil Young loses ring before [7] finales (7)
>   15. [14] beginners mischievously zero in to national park (8)
>   16. Game reserve rampant as a Maria inside [28]'s borders (6 4)
>   17. [20] capital sides in arbor duck hunt getting rid of hot DC mosque (4'1 5)
>   18. [17]'s edges both ways with large saline lake (5)
>   19. Planck moves head back around [15]'s capital, a historic town (4)
>   20. [9] capital's heart gets a bottomless lake archipelago (6)
>   21. National park's headless anime holds shelled [8] currency (6)
>   22. Polyhedrons follow skinned Anubis with [51] capital's heart making ancient tombs (6 8)
>   23. Latin wife east of [1]'s capital city full of history (5)
>   24. Losing second chance, [41] lets imp freely to a ruin (6 5)
>   25. [24]'s top three return after two leading Jews for national park (5)
>   26. [23] IM gadget conceals city (6)
>   27. Mind boasts fanatically about brief [19] capital's graves (7 5)
>   28. Convoluted car band leads part of [36] national park (4 1'6)
>   29. [48]'s heart in thirds to pot-boil pumpkin tofu leading to ancient city (8)
>   30. [27]'s leaders go west by hideous double-headed groom's market town (5-5)
>   31. Heartless fascism crudely follows rest of [26] back to mountain formation (3 6)
>   32. Soldier holds half of [37]'s headless capital village (5)
>   33. [13]'s borders hold back Asian people leading to town with waterfalls (5)
>   34. [47] capital's leader Ben R leaves biosensor to town near canyon (6)
>   35. Large, leaderless [34] briefly has a national park (6)
>   36. [44]'s premier duos follow prince of boas oddly to mountain (4 6)
>   37. Faunal reserve in [32]'s capital (3)
>   38. Move back and forth behind [2]'s former president leading to monolith (4 4)
>   39. Gamey endings by inner [35] makes city with palaces (6)
>   40. [5] capital removes large wing, gets medium capital (4)
>   41. [18] loses Dench leading to waterfall (4)
>   42. Wines taken from unorthodox [3] national park (3)
>   43. Surfing town's actress Julia alongside leaders of [52]'s capital (11)
>   44. [39] strikes second and third with uneven true mean nail mountain (9)
>   45. Old Eli returns to get [21]'s initials and extremely habitable islands (4 2 3)
>   46. [11]'s bottom three follow shelled coral island (6)
>   47. Lose with abnormal brief [33] inside lake (3 4)
>   48. [53]' second following reconstructed Baku nature reserve (5)
>   49. Volcanic village is [31]'s neighbour with strange radical seas (3 3 9)
>   50. [38] coin with head lost to natural park (3)
>   51. Natural monument is a venue of the jazzy ABBAs having [30]'s extremities (6 2 3 7)
>   52. Mountain tribe finally switched sides in coup within [40] capital's borders (2 5)
>   53. Almost [22] capital second-to-last with inner salad volcano (8)
>   54. Mixed-up Eve led a [29] natural reserve (6 2 3)

Comment: jafe, how do my countries and answers look so far? I was a little iffy on a couple of them, especially the ones remaining, but I think I got most of them. Great puzzle! :)

Comment: Could 9 have 10 letters instead of 11? I think I have it...

Comment: @El-Guest Oops, 10 is correct. Fixed now.

Comment: thanks! Are the rest of mine correct now?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe I have them all now, here they are with credits attached as they are due. Thanks kindly to @Chris Cudmore and @NudgeNudge for the assists, please upvote their answers!

> 1. (**LESOTHO**). Masculine (MALE) half TV (T) star (SUN) by wild and unopened **Kenya** (YANE) waterfall = **MALETSUNYANE**. (Thanks, @Chris Cudmore!!) 
>  
>  
>  2. (**SOUTH AFRICA**). Tunisia's leader (T) capable (ABLE) before peak (MOUNTAIN) mesa = **TABLE MOUNTAIN**. (Thanks, @Chris Cudmore!!) 
>  3. (**ESWATINI**). Mountain is returning (SI) by Liberia with no rail signs (Liberia - letters r,a,i,l => BE), twice (BEBE) = **SIBEBE**. 
>  4. (**MOZAMBIQUE**). Sao Tome & Principe's honorific (SAO) next to violently beat oasis (beat oasis rearranged -> SEBASTIAO) fort = Fort of **SAO SEBASTIAO**. 
>  5. (**MALAWI**). Cape Verde's first (CAPE) Shakespeare king (MAC-beth) leads Shakespeare king's (LEAR) lake resort = **CAPE MACLEAR**. 
>  6. (**ZAMBIA**). Non-deceased (LIVING) Tanzania town (Stonetown) without town (STONE) is former capital = **LIVINGSTONE**. 
>  7. (**ZIMBABWE**). Grand (GREAT) Mozambique's neighbour (ZIMBABWE) is ruined city = **GREAT ZIMBABWE**. 
>  8. (**BOTSWANA**). Agreed, (OK) audiovisual (AV) Angola with murderous Bundy's (TED) parts forms river mouth = **OKAVANGO DELTA**. (Thanks, @Chris Cudmore!!) 
>  9. (**NAMIBIA**). Dry lake's unconventional US olives (US olives rearranged = SO__USVLEI) draw in Guinea-Bissau couple (couple is SS) = **SOSSUSVLEI**. 
>  10. (**ANGOLA**). Chaotic Zambia (ZAMBIA rearranged) gets a (add A) large turn (add U) for medium (replace M with L) beach (4 4) = **BAIA AZUL**. 
>  11. (**DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF CONGO**). Ape (BONOBO) follows girl (LOLA) alongside Ivory Coast capital's (Yamassoukro) leaders (YA) to sanctuary = **LOLA YA BONOBO**. 
>  12. (**TANZANIA**) Aged (OLD) user interface (UI)  about the case of Seychelles' capital (Victoria => VA) gorge = **OLDUVAI**. 
>  13. (**BURUNDI**). Get (GET )one (I) back (ITEG) inside Guinea's borders (GA) leads to capital = **GITEGA**. 
>  14. (**RWANDA**). Forest capital of Neil (N) Young loses ring (Young - o = YUNG) before Zimbabwe finales (WE) = **NYUNGWE**. 
>  15. (**UGANDA**). Rwanda beginners (RW) mischievously zero in (anagram to ENZORI) to national park = **RWENZORI**. 
>  16. (**KENYA**). Game reserve rampant as a Maria (AASAI MAR) inside Mauritania's borders (M A) = **MAASAI MARA**. 
>  17. (**SOMALIA**). Eritrea ((A)smar(a)) capital sides in arbor duck hunt getting rid of hot DC (arbor duck hunt - hot DC = arb rukun) mosque = **ARBA'A RUKUN**. (Thanks, @NudgeNudge!!) 
>  18. (**DJIBOUTI**). (S)omali(a)'s edges both ways with large (L) saline lake = **ASSAL**. (Thanks, @NudgeNudge!!) 
>  19. (**ETHIOPIA**). Planck (MAX) moves head back around (AX_M) Uganda's capital (U), a historic town = **AXUM**. 
>  20. (**ERITREA**). Namibia capital's (Windhoek) heart (DH) gets a (DH + A => DAH) bottomless lake (LAKE - E = LAK) archipelago = **DAHLAK**. 
>  21. (**SOUTH SUDAN**) National park's headless anime (NIME) holds shelled Botswana currency shelled PULA = UL) = **NIMULE**. 
>  22. (**SUDAN**). Polyhedrons (PYRAMIDS) follow skinned Anubis (NUBI) with Madagascar capital's (Antananarivo) heart (AN) making ancient tombs = **NUBIAN PYRAMIDS**. 
>  23. (**EGYPT**). Latin wife (UXOR) east of (L)esotho/(L)ibya/(L)iberia's capital city full of history = **LUXOR**. (Thanks, @NudgeNudge!!) 
>  24. (**LIBYA**) Losing second chance, Ghana lets imp freely to a (Ghana lets imp - H = GANALETSIMP, rearranges to LEPTIS MAGNA) ruin = **LEPTIS MAGNA**. 
>  25. (**TUNISIA**). Libya's top three return (BIL) after two leading Jews (JE) for national park = **JEBIL**. 
>  26. (**ALGERIA**). Egyp(t IM gad)get conceals city = **TIMGAD**. (Thanks, @NudgeNudge!!) 
>  27. (**MOROCCO**). Mind boasts (S_DIAN TOMBS) fanatically about brief Ethiopia capital's (Addis Ababa briefly = AA) graves = **SAADIAN TOMBS**. 
>  28. (**MAURITANIA**). Convoluted car band (BANC D'AR) leads part of Equatorial Guinea (GUIN) national park = **BANC D'ARGUIN**. 
>  
>  29. (**MALI**). Gambia's heart (MB) in thirds to poT-boIl pUmpKin TofU (TI__UKTU) leading to ancient city = **TIMBUKTU**. 
>  30. (**BURKINA FASO**) Morocco's leaders (MOR) go (GO) west (ROM) by hideous double-headed (times two) groom's (groom, rearranged) market town (5-5) = **GOROM-GOROM**. 
>  31. (**NIGER**). Heartless fascism (FASISM) crudely (rearranged, MASSIF) follows rest of Algeria (RIA) back (backwards, AIR) to mountain formation = **AIR MASSIF**. 
>  32. (**CHAD**) Soldier (GI) holds half of Cameroon's headless capital village (Yaounde - y = AOUNDE; half is AOU = **GAOUI**. 
>  33. (**CENTRAL AFRICAN REPUBLIC**). Burundi's borders (BI) hold back Asian people (LAO <-> OAL) leading to town with waterfalls = **BOALI**. 
>  34. (**REPUBLIC OF CONGO**). Senegal capital's leader (Dakar leader = D) Ben R leaves biosensor (biosensor - ben r = IOSSO) to town near canyon (Diosso Gorge) = **DIOSSO**. 
>  35. (**GABON**). Large (L), leaderless Republic of Congo (ONGO) briefly has a (insert A) national park = **LOANGO**. 
>  36. (**EQUATORIAL GUINEA**). Sierra Leone's premier duos (SI LE) follow PrInCe Of BoAs (PICO BA) oddly to mountain = **PICO BASILE**. 
>  37. (**CAMEROON**) Faunal reserve in Chad's capital (N'DJAmena) = **DJA**. 
>  38. (**NIGERIA**). Move back and forth (ROCK) behind South Africa's former president (ZUMA) leading to monolith = **ZUMA ROCK**. 
>  39. (**BENIN**). Gamey endings (MEY) by inner Gabon (ABO) makes city with palaces = **ABOMEY**. 
>  40. (**TOGO**). Malawi capital (Lilongwe) removes large wing (Lilongwe - L WING = LOE), gets medium (LOE + M = LOME) capital = **LOME**. 
>  41. (**GHANA**). Djibouti loses Dench (Djibouti - Judi = boti) leading to waterfall (4) = **BOTI**. (Thanks, @NudgeNudge!!) 
>  42. (**IVORY COAST**). Wines taken from unorthodox Eswatini (Eswatini - wines and rearranged => TAI) national park = **TAI**. 
>  43. (**LIBERIA**). Surfing town's actress Julia (ROBERTS) alongside leaders of Mauritius's capital (PORT Louis) = **ROBERTSPORT**. 
>  44. (**SIERRA LEONE**). Benin strikes second and third (Benin - en = BIN) with uneven TrUe MeAn NaIl mountain = **BINTUMANI**. 
>  45. (**GUINEA**) Old Eli (ILE D LO) returns to get South Sudan's initials (SS) and extremely (E) habitable islands = **ILES DE LOS**. 
>  46. (**GUINEA-BISSAU**). Democratic Republic of Congo's bottom three (NGO) follow shelled coral (ORA) island = **ORANGO**. 
>  47. (**SENEGAL**). Lose (L__ _OSE) with abnormal brief Central African Republic (CAR rearranged = AC R) inside lake = **LAC ROSE**. 
>  48. (**GAMBIA**). Comoros' second (O) following reconstructed Baku (ABUK) nature reserve = **ABUKO**. 
>  49. (**CAPE VERDE**). Volcanic village is Niger's neighbour (CHAD) with strange radical seas (radical seas anagrammed gives AS CALDEIRAS) = **CHA DAS CALDEIRAS**. 
>  50. (**SAO TOME & PRINCIPE**). Nigeria coin (KOBO) with head lost (- K) to natural park = **OBO**. 
>  51. (**MADAGASCAR**). Natural monument is a venue of the (AVENUE OF THE) jazzy ABBAs (BA__ABS) having Burkina Faso's extremities (OB) = **AVENUE OF THE BAOBABS**. 
>  52. (**MAURITIUS**). Mountain tribe finally (tribe, finally = E) switched sides in coup (COUP switched sides = POUC) within Togo capital's borders (L__E) = **LE POUCE**. 
>  53. (**COMOROS**) Almost Sudan capital (KHARToum => KARTH) second-to-last with inner salad (ALA) volcano = **KARTHALA**. 
>  54. (**SEYCHELLES**). Mixed-up (Eve led a Mali) natural reserve = **VALLEE DE MAI**.

Comment: Try Kenya (unopened) = Enya Wild =  YANE

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisCudmore -- that's really clever!

Comment: Jafe's puzzles usually are.

Comment: Everything correct except #52.

Comment: That makes more sense, @jafe! New guess for #52!

Comment: All correct. Nice job!

Comment: Thanks very much @jafe!! That was lots of fun, love your cryptic geography puzzles!

Comment: Glad to hear it! Currently working on a seque[l](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIenJ.png)...

Answer (score 5):

**Partial:**

> 17 (**SOMALIA**). Eritrea/Ethiopia/Nigeria ((*A*)smar(*a*)/(*A*)ddis Abab(*a*)/(*A*)buj(*a*)) capital sides in arbor duck hunt getting rid of hot DC (arbor duck hunt - hot DC = *arb rukun*) mosque = **ARBA'A RUKUN**
> 18 (**DJIBOUTI**). (*S*)omali(*a*)'s edges both ways with large (L) **saline lake** = **ASSAL**
> 22 (**SUDAN**). Polyhedrons (*pyramids*) follow skinned A(*nubi*)s with Angola/Madagascar (Lu(*an*)da/Antan(*an*)arivo) capital's heart making **ancient tombs** = **NUBIAN PYRAMIDS**
> 23 (**EGYPT**). Latin wife (*uxor*) east of (*L*)esotho/(*L*)ibya/(*L*)iberia's capital **city full of history** - **LUXOR**
> 24. Losing second chance, Ghana lets imp freely to a ruin (6 5)
> 26 (**ALGERIA**). Egyp(*t IM gad*)get conceals **city** - **TIMGAD**
> 31. Heartless fascism crudely follows rest of Algeria back to mountain formation (3 6)
> 41 (**GHANA**). Djibouti loses Dench (Djibouti - Judi = boti) leading to **waterfall** (4) = **BOTI**
> 53. Almost Sudan capital second-to-last with inner salad volcano (8)

Answer (score 2):

Partial:  I'm not really playing here, just adding a few.

> 2. [25 Tanzania | Togo | Tunisia]'s leader capable before peak mesa (5 8) 
>  **T+ABLE MOUNTAIN**[Republic of South Africa]
> 8. Agreed, audiovisual [10] with murderous Bundy's parts forms river mouth (8 5)
> **OK+AV+ANGO DELTA**  ([BOTSWANA])  Incomplete parsing. Use TED for Bundy  
> 34. [47] capital's leader Ben R leaves biosensor to town near canyon (6)
> **D+IOSSO**  (Republic of Congo)